# after chroot: apt-get update (Err and Failed to fetch - BootableFlashFromHarddiskInstall)

Tags: apt, virtualbox, live-usb, chroot, custom-distributions

I'm following [BootableFlashFromHarddiskInstall tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MakeALiveCD/DVD/BootableFlashFromHarddiskInstall) for making a live CD from my current Ubuntu installation.

Ubuntu 14.04 on VirtualBox. I checked internet connection of virtual machine as normal user(How can I check internet connection of chroot?).

After this step problems started:

```
sudo chroot ${WORK}/rootfs /bin/bash
```

Nothing happened or changed no output after this command(**$LANG** environment variable? What is **the purpose**?):

```
LANG=
```

After apt-get update

```
apt-get update
```

I'm getting these errors:

[image]

Here is history of my normal acccount:

[image]

So what is the actual problem?

Is Chroot not connected to internet?
- or - tr.archive.ubuntu.com could be a problem?

I checked `sudo apt-get update` as normal user(mertyildiran) it is working.

But in chroot `apt-get update` - or - `sudo apt-get update` both of them not working

**EDIT:**

/etc/resolv.conf in chroot directory:

[image]

Comment: If you're in a chroot, did you copy `/etc/resolv.conf` from the original system to the chroot?

Comment: @muru I edited question. I can't copy: "cp: not writing through dangling symlink ‘work/rootfs/etc/resolv.conf’"

Comment: Since it's a chroot, you probably don't have `/run` set up. So, just delete the link and then copy.

Comment: @muru ´sudo mkdir work/rootfs/run/resolvconf´ and ´sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf work/rootfs/run/resolvconf/´ solved my problem. Thank you you can write an answer I will mark as accepted.

Comment: @muru should I delete the link, hmm.., you right It is more appropriate. Thx! :)

Comment: @muru One more thing. Why resolv.conf become as a link? Did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Within a chroot, it is likely that `resolv.conf` is not properly set up (it could be a symlink to a non-existent file, or it could be empty and so on). Therefore a common bit of advice when setting up chroots is to copy the host's `resolv.conf`:

```
mv chroot/etc/resolv.conf{,.bak}
cp /etc/resolv.conf chroot/etc/resolv.conf
```

Then you can restore the original, if it was a proper file.

On many modern systems, `resolv.conf` is a symlink to a file `/run`, since it is dynamically managed by [`resolvconf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/resolvconf.8). On a Debian based system, you can always recreate the link using:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

Comment: For people who a bit slow like me, you need to replace `chroot` with the appropriate directory (like say `/mnt`) to use the commands.

Comment: works like a charm !